# How to optimize user search in OIM 11gR2PS2

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

We have a large user base in our Oracle Identity Manager system. We have over 0.5 million records in USR table. We have our trusted reconciliation scheduled jobs running every 2 hours. While running trusted reconciliation scheduled jobs for LDAP and FlatFile, OIM is firing a search query on USR table everytime to list all active users. Due to large user base, this query takes a lot of time and our scheduled job which is supposed to bring less than 100 insers/updates takes around 1 hour to complete. Is there a way to optimize it? I have gone through the OIM optimizations guide and have done all the optimizations suggested by Oracle which includes putting USR table in default buffer pool. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt there are many people on this site familiar with OIM.  But there are plenty of people who can help tune a query.  Can you find the slowest queries and post them here along with their explain plan?  For example, find the longest queries like this: `select elapsed_time/1000000 seconds, sql_id, sql_text from gv$sql order by elapsed_time desc;`.  Generate their execution plans like this: `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => '7u49y06aqxg1s'));`

Comment: As per my findings, the problem is that it's not a custom query. This query is fired by OIM application server itself while executing the trusted recon. Thus optimizing the query wouldn't help. Thus, my guess is that something needs to be done at database/OIM level.

Comment: A query can still be optimized even if it can't be modified.  It's more difficult, but still possible.  Keep drilling down to you find the smallest part that is the slowest, and post it here, whatever it is.  Somebody may have a way to improve it.